# Create aws_transfer_ssh_key from a map of user to SSH keys

Tags: terraform, terraform-aws-modules

I'm trying to create a transfer key from a map users to SSH keys

```
content_users = {
  "master" = [
    "ssh-rsa ...",
    "ssh-rsa ...",
    "ssh-rsa ...",
  ]
  "test" = [
    "ssh-rsa ...",
    "ssh-rsa ...",
  ]
}
```

The `aws_transfer_user` part is easy enough

```
resource "aws_transfer_user" "content" {
  for_each  = var.content_users
  server_id = aws_transfer_server.content.id
  user_name = each.key
  role      = aws_iam_role.transfer.arn
}
```

But I am trying to figure out how to do the `aws_transfer_key` which only accepts one ssh key

```
resource "aws_transfer_ssh_key" "content" {
  for_each = var.content_users
 server_id = aws_transfer_server.content.id
  user_name = each.key
  body      = "... SSH key ..."
}
```

I am thinking it is something I just have to follow with https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resource "aws_transfer_ssh_key" "content" {
  for_each = toset(flatten([
    for user, keys in var.content_users : [
      for key in keys : "${user}:@:${key}"
    ]
  ]))
  server_id = aws_transfer_server.content.id
  user_name = split(":@:", each.value)[0]
  body      = split(":@:", each.value)[1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this a little different. I didn't like the idea of the resource name containing the full public ssh key value. I use the below code in a module that was created.

I used a map variable like this.

```
variable "customers" {
  description = "A map of customer usernames and ssh public keys"
  type = map(object({
    keys = list(string)
  }))
}
```

ex.

```
customers = {
  cust1 = { 
    keys = [
      "ssh-rsa..."
    ]
  },
  cust2 = {
    keys = [
      "ssh-rsa...",
      "ssh-rsa...",
      "ssh-rsa..."
    ]
  },
}
```

First I had to flatten it and I also added an index while doing so.

```
locals {
  customers = flatten([
    for customer, sshkeys in var.customers : [
      for k, v in sshkeys.keys : {
        client = customer
        index  = k
        key    = v
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

Then I used it in the resource. The index is required otherwise the map fails and asks you to group the client keys using ..., but we do not want this.

```
resource "aws_transfer_ssh_key" "this" {
  for_each  = { for each in local.customers : "${each.client}.${each.index}" => each }
  server_id = aws_transfer_server.this.id
  user_name = "customer-${each.value.client}"
  body      = each.value.key
}
```

This should generate numbered resources for the transfer ssh key like the follwing...

```
cust1.0
cust2.0
cust2.1
cust2.2
```

The index value resets for each client. You could add a +1 to the index so it starts at 1 instead of 0 as well.